# sys.frame, sys.nframe, etc. in R

Tags: r, operating-system, environment

could someone please explain to me what these various environment functions do specifically? ie which one returns what frame? i am thoroughly confused after reading the documentation (http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/sys.parent.html)

Let's put some structure on the question:

```
x = 1; y=2; z=3;
f = function() { ls(); ls(envir=sys.frame());}
#this first prints the contents of this function and then of the global environment
```

I am trying to understand how one can access environments of calling functions and to know which environment you are in.  For example `g` could have called `f`:

```
g = function() { somevar=1; f() }
```

If I wanted to get the contents of `g`, how would i do that? What is the difference between a frame and an environment?

Comment: Frames and environments can certainly be confusing, no doubt. But this question is a bit broad. If you had a specific example (even a trivial, toy example) of some code that illustrated behavior you were trying to understand, that would potentially make this a great question, rather than a "meh" one.

Comment: @joran: good call. let me put in context what i am trying to do

Comment: I have some notes on the topic at https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/environments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parent.frame()` refers to the calling environment. You normally don't need the rest of them.  For your example use this to list `somevar` :

```
f <- function() ls(parent.frame())
```

Comment: interesting! thanks. what is the difference between a frame and an environment?

Comment: A frame is an environment on the call stack.

Comment: this is unrelated but could you also tell me how to compare environments? for example `.GlobalEnv == sys.frame()` isn't possible..

Comment: @Alex if you are wondering why make the distinction between an environment and an environment on the callstack, aside from the environment a function is called in (its parent "frame"), a function is also bound to the environment in which it was defined, which is what you get when you call `parent.env()`.

Comment: oh so `parent.env()` gives you the environemtn they are defined in vs `parent.frame()` gives you the environment they are evaluated in? did i understand correctly?

Comment: @Alex that's right. actually, you'd want to say 'environment they are called in' instead of 'evaluated in', since function calls are evaluated in the environment in which the function is defined.

Comment: @Alex, Try: `e <- new.env(); f <- new.env(); identical(e, f)` . Environments form a tree and the parent of an environmet `e` is given by `parent.env(e)`.  Note that a parent frame refers to the parent on the call stack and has nothing to do with the parent environment (in terms of the tree of environments).